# After adding forth parameter to database, error occurs while POSTing data via Postman

Tags: php, mysql, rest, api, crud

I am trying to POST new entry into database. When there is four parameters:
id
title
description
link
code is working fine. But after I add fifth 'image' parameter and try to POST via Postman, code is returning: "Error while adding entry".

API is written in PHP with mysqli connection to database.

```
if(isset($_POST['title'])&&isset($_POST['description'])&&isset($_POST['link'])&&isset($_POST['image'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$image = $_POST['image'];

$query = "INSERT INTO votes( title, description, link, image) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$title,$description,$link,$image);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->affected_rows == 1){
        $response["success"] = 1;           
        $response["message"] = "News Successfully Added";           

    }else{
        //Some error while inserting
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Error while adding entry";
    }                   
}else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = mysqli_error($con);
}}else{
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "missing mandatory parameters";}echo json_encode($response);?>
```

I can't figure out why is not working after I add one column in database, but its working when there is no 'image' column.

Comment: you have 4 placeholders but only 3 identifiers `'sss'` should be `'ssss'`??

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure what those identifiers means. To be sure, 's' stands for String, 'i' stand for Integer etc. How can I identify date, year, image...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arguments need to be correct**

i - integer
d - double
s - string
b - BLOB

```
if(isset($_POST['title'])&&isset($_POST['description'])&&isset($_POST['link'])&&isset($_POST['image'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$image = $_POST['image'];

$query = "INSERT INTO votes( title, description, link, image) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssss",$title,$description,$link,$image);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->affected_rows == 1){
        $response["success"] = 1;           
        $response["message"] = "News Successfully Added";           

    }else{
        //Some error while inserting
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Error while adding entry";
    }                   
}else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = mysqli_error($con);
}}else{
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "missing mandatory parameters";}echo json_encode($response);?>
```